# Children’s sci fi novel about young girl who befriends a wheel-shaped alien on its planet

Tags: identification-request

I’m looking for the title of a book I read a book from a library in Kentucky in roughly 1977-78. It’s a chapter book for the roughly 3rd to 5th grade reading level in English. I don’t remember any illustrations (perhaps at the beginning of each chapter?). It’s about a young girl who travels to an alien planet with her family.  The aliens on the planet are wheel-shaped (if memory serves), and the girl befriends one of the young aliens. I think the humans are trying to colonize the planet, and the girl tries to help the aliens keep their land…something like that. It was one of my favorite books I read that summer. Anyone remember this book?

Comment: [This Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolling_and_wheeled_creatures_in_fiction_and_legend) lists some possibilities. As it is, you've not provided much to go on. Could it be one of L Frank Baum's books? Otherwise, length, date, setting, illustrations, reading level, format, anything about the characters, all would be useful, as already mentioned.

Comment: Stuart - thank you for that link. It didn’t have the book I’m looking for, but I appreciate you looking it up!

Comment: This looks similar to the story described here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/261827/70s-80s-childrens-book-about-space-colonist-boy-who-realises-by-telepathy-that   - There's no answer yet but if it is the same it might help you remember more details.